# Adding an image to a javascript slideshow

Tags: javascript

I have a slideshow all put together but I'm having trouble using an `onClick` to insert an additional image. What am I missing?

```js
function newDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsById("photo");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  };
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="photo" id="photo" value="http://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uuuploads/cute-baby-animals/cute-baby-animals-23.jpg" />
<button id="addPicture" onclick="newDivs(+1)">Add New Image</button>
```

Comment: Do you get an error message?  What does it say?

Comment: the onclick is not inserting any images AND there's no such thing as `getElementsById`.

Comment: Could you please explain what are the errors you get and what is the behaviour you would expect or would like?

Comment: I'm just not getting the image to insert.

Answer (score 0):

You have many mistakes to begin with:

wrong:

var x = document.getElementsById("photo");

right:

var x = document.getElementById("photo").val;

Answer (score 0):

There a few things you need to understand.

- When you want to perform action on multiple element never try id. (ID always return only single element. and it can not be run with multiple element.
- Your Javascript function is wrong `getElementsById`. correct is `getElementById`. just because of as i said ID return single element ( `getElementById` - just remove (s) from the function.
- try to use query selector. like i have used in your example.(`querySelectorAll`)
- Query selector function will help you a lot !. and if you are new in javascript. if you can try [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)  it will be really easy for you.
- If you want to display image you need to play with `img` tag. right now you are getting URL from input tag and trying to hide them doesn't make sense ;
- Here is the your solution

```js
var i= 0;
var slideIndex = 0;
function newDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.querySelectorAll(".photo");
  console.log(x);
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  };
  
  for (var index = 0; index < x.length; index++) {
  console.log(x[index].style);
    x[index].style.display = 'none';
  }
  console.log(slideIndex);
  x[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="photo" name="photo" id="photo" value="http://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uuuploads/cute-baby-animals/cute-baby-animals-23.jpg" />
<button id="addPicture" onclick="newDivs(+1)">Add New Image</button>
```